# My database is already updated but my android studio still not updating, still showing the previous fetched database

Tags: java, android, mysql

How to update the to new database, because I try updating my database and it still not changing, it still getting the old database. I'm using php files to connect to database mysql and parse the data using JSON.

Here is code..

```
public class TampilUser extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    CustomAdapter customAdapter;
    ArrayList<User> user = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tampil_user);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listUser);

        getJSON("Link here");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getJSON("Link here");
    }

    private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {

        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    loadIntoListView(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    sb.setLength(0);
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    con.disconnect();
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    }

    public void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        user = new ArrayList<>();
        user.clear();
        User u;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String email = obj.getString("email");
            String nama = obj.getString("nama");

            u = new User();
            u.setEmail(email);
            u.setNama(nama);

            user.add(u);
        }
        customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(),user);
        listView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String nama = customAdapter.user.get(position).getNama();
                String email = customAdapter.user.get(position).getEmail();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailUser.class);

                i.putExtra("email", email);
                i.putExtra("nama", nama);
                startActivityForResult(i, 0);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        getJSON("Link here"); 
        customAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        customAdapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
}
```

I'm using custom adapter, and this is the get view code in custom adapter extends base adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

   if(convertView==null)
   {
       convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.daftar_user,parent,false);
   }
   TextView textView_email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_email);
   TextView textView_nama = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView_nama);

   textView_email.setText(user.get(position).getEmail());
   textView_nama.setText(user.get(position).getNama());

   return convertView;
}
```

I have try many thing and still not changing.. And I'm still new at stackoverflow, I will appreciate ur help so much.. Thank you...

Comment: does it give you updated data when you access http://www.trigroupindonesia.com/php/read_user.php from browser?

Comment: The update process is no problem, the data in the database is updated, and the browser already show the updated data. I use toast to show the data that parsed from browser, but the data is still the old data..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is already fixed.

I just put the customadapter.notifyDataSetChanged() before start a new intent on click list view